# C# OpenHardwareMonitorlib.dll can't use index for different cores

Tags: c#, dll, openhardwaremonitor

I am using OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll to make a program for myself, but i want to be able to view each core's load and temp.
Click on the Image link to view the WMI below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUSPB.png)

So as you can see each instance i.e each core of my intel cpu has 4 cores so 4 instances ... well 5 because of total load, i want to be able to use the index to allow me to retrieve each instance, but I am struggling to do so, as the .dll file only has public get accessors if i'm correct, correct me if i'm wrong.

I've tried setting the sensor.Index to a variable but error comes up as read only so yano ... I've tried if control structures e.g. if sensor.Index == 1 ... But it doesn't work it automatically grabs the last index.

So here is my code below that i've come up with so far. Please focus on the issue instead of my superfluous code i'm only a student.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace Hardware
{
    public partial class Temps : Form
    {
    Timer timer;

    private double ramusedpt;
    private double ramusedptx;
    private double systemram;
    int xaxis;
    Computer myComputer;
    ISensor NvdGPUTemperatureSensor, ATIGPUTemperatureSensor, CPUTemperatureSensor, NvdGPUFanSpeed, ATIGPUFanSpeed,
        NvdGPUFanCtrl, GPUShaderSpeed, GPUMemoryLoad, CPUFanSpeed, RamUsage, RamUsed, CPULoadSensor, CPUCoreTest;
    public Temps()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myComputer = new Computer();
        myComputer.Open();
        myComputer.GPUEnabled = true;
        myComputer.CPUEnabled = true;
        myComputer.FanControllerEnabled = true;
        myComputer.MainboardEnabled = true;
        myComputer.RAMEnabled = true;
        myComputer.HDDEnabled = true;
        string ram = Getcomponent("Win32_OperatingSystem", "TotalVisibleMemorySize");
        systemram = double.Parse(ram);
        systemram = Math.Round(systemram / 1048576);
        foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
        {
            foreach (var subhardware in hardwareItem.SubHardware)
            {
                subhardware.Update();
                if (subhardware.Sensors.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var sensor in subhardware.Sensors)
                    {
                        if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Fan)
                        {
                            CPUFanSpeed = sensor;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        NvdGPUTemperatureSensor = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuAti)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        ATIGPUTemperatureSensor  = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        CPUTemperatureSensor = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            // GPU Fan Sensor
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Fan)
                    {
                        NvdGPUFanSpeed = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuAti)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Fan)
                    {
                        ATIGPUFanSpeed = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            // GPU Fan Control
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Control)
                    {
                        NvdGPUFanCtrl = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            //
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Clock)
                    {
                        GPUShaderSpeed = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                foreach(var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load)
                    {
                        GPUMemoryLoad = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.RAM)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Data)
                    {
                        RamUsage = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.RAM)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Factor)
                    {
                        RamUsed = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load)
                    {
                        CPULoadSensor = sensor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 500;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string gpu = Getcomponent("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
        GPUlabel.Text = gpu;
        gpuFanLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(NvdGPUFanSpeed.Identifier);
        cpulabel.Text = Convert.ToString(CPUTemperatureSensor.Name);
        //GPU Temp sensor
        if (NvdGPUTemperatureSensor != null && GPUlabel.Text.Contains("NVIDIA"))
        {
            NvdGPUTemperatureSensor.Hardware.Update();
            gpuCurrent.Text = Convert.ToString(NvdGPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
            gpuMax.Text = Convert.ToString(NvdGPUTemperatureSensor.Max);
        }
        else if (ATIGPUTemperatureSensor != null && GPUlabel.Text.Contains("AMD"))
        {
            ATIGPUTemperatureSensor.Hardware.Update();
            gpuCurrent.Text = Convert.ToString(ATIGPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
            gpuMax.Text = Convert.ToString(ATIGPUTemperatureSensor.Max);
        }
        else
        {
            gpuCurrent.Text = "N/A";
            gpuMax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        // CPU temp sensor
        if (CPUTemperatureSensor != null)
        {
            CPUTemperatureSensor.Hardware.Update();
            cputxtval.Text = Convert.ToString(CPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
            cputxtmax.Text = Convert.ToString(CPUTemperatureSensor.Max);
        }
        else
        {
            cputxtval.Text = "N/A";
            cputxtmax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        // GPU Fan Speed
        if (NvdGPUFanSpeed != null && GPUlabel.Text.Contains("NVIDIA"))
        {
            NvdGPUFanSpeed.Hardware.Update();
            gpuFanTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(NvdGPUFanSpeed.Value);
            gpuFanMax.Text = Convert.ToString(NvdGPUFanSpeed.Max);
        }
        else if (ATIGPUFanSpeed != null && GPUlabel.Text.Contains("AMD"))
        {
            ATIGPUFanSpeed.Hardware.Update();
            gpuFanTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(ATIGPUFanSpeed.Value);
            gpuFanMax.Text = Convert.ToString(ATIGPUFanSpeed.Max);
        }
        else
        {
            gpuFanTxt.Text = "N/A";
            gpuFanMax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        // GPU Fan Speed Control
        if (NvdGPUFanCtrl != null)
        {
            NvdGPUFanCtrl.Hardware.Update();
            gpufanpb.Value = ((int)NvdGPUFanCtrl.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to grab Fan Control value.", "Failure");
        }
        // GPU Shader Speed
        if (GPUShaderSpeed != null )
        {
            GPUShaderSpeed.Hardware.Update();
            gpuShaderVal.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(GPUShaderSpeed.Value));
            gpuShaderMax.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(GPUShaderSpeed.Max));
        }
        else
        {
            gpuShaderVal.Text = "N/A";
            gpuShaderMax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        // GPU Memory Load
        if (GPUMemoryLoad != null)
        {
            GPUMemoryLoad.Hardware.Update();
            gpuTestVal.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round((double)GPUMemoryLoad.Value, 1));
            gpuTestMax.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round((double)GPUMemoryLoad.Max, 1));
            gpuMempb.Value = ((int)GPUMemoryLoad.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            gpuTestVal.Text = "N/A";
            gpuTestMax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        // CPU Fan Speed
        if (CPUFanSpeed != null)
        {
            CPUFanSpeed.Hardware.Update();
            cpuFanVal.Text = Convert.ToString((int)(float)CPUFanSpeed.Value);
            cpuFanMax.Text = Convert.ToString((int)(float)CPUFanSpeed.Max);
        }
        else
        {
            cpuFanVal.Text = "N/A";
            cpuFanMax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        // RAM Usage
        if (RamUsage != null)
        {
            RamUsage.Hardware.Update();
            ramVal.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round((double)RamUsage.Value, 2));
            ramValMax.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round((double)RamUsage.Max, 2));
            ramusedpt = Math.Round((double)RamUsage.Value, 2);
            ramusedptx = Math.Round((Double)RamUsage.Max, 2);

        }
        else
        {
            ramVal.Text = "N/A";
            ramValMax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        // Ram Used
        if (RamUsage != null)
        {

            usedRamVal.Text = Convert.ToString(systemram - ramusedpt);
            usedRamMax.Text = Convert.ToString(systemram - ramusedptx);
        }
        else
        {   
            usedRamVal.Text = "N/A";
            usedRamMax.Text = "N/A";
        }
        if (CPUCoreTest != null)
        {
            CPUCoreTest.Hardware.Update();
            cpucore2txt.Text = Convert.ToString(CPUCoreTest.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cpucore2txt.Text = "N/A";
        }
        try
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xaxis++, CPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
            chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(xaxis, NvdGPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
            chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(xaxis, ramusedpt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    private static string Getcomponent(string hwclass, string syntax)
    {
        StringBuilder comp = new StringBuilder();
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
        foreach (ManagementObject mj in mos.Get())
            comp.Append(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
        return comp.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

http://openhardwaremonitor.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/OpenHardwareMonitor-WMI.pdf

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the if control structure working.
Posting as it may help people in future

```
if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                {
                    foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                    {
                        if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load)
                        {
                            if (sensor.Index == 1)
                            {
                                CPUCoreTest2 = sensor;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Basically the index for 0 is cpu total.
1 is core 1.
2 is core 2.
3 is core 3.
4 iscore 4.etc ... :)